# Flutter TextFormField: TextInputType.number is not working properly when I use controller

Tags: flutter, controller, textformfield

When I use controller for Textformfield and want to define the keyboardtype as TextinputType.number, I can't input any thing unless I input any non-numeric character such as "." or "-".

```
final TextEditingController _questionIndexController = TextEditingController();

return Container(
  height: _avaliableHeight * 0.05,
  width: _sideBarWidth * 0.25,
  child: TextFormField(
    // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    controller: _questionIndexController,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10,),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 5.0),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
    ),
    
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
 ),
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known Flutter bug when using `TextInputType.number` https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88833#issuecomment-906301512

The workaround is to set the selection offset to 0 in the controller:

```dart
final TextEditingController _questionIndexController = TextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue(text: '', selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0)));
```

Comment: Working like charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Despite the Sipho's workaround is working well, I would advice to declare your controller outside the build method, and if possible make it final, and it should work perfectly.

```
final TextEditingController _questionIndexController = TextEditingController();
```